# How to solve "Not Secure" warning on my heroku app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a Heroku app which is on a free plan like myappsucks.herokuapp.com but recently that website is showing a not secure warning when I open it on my browser. Can anyone help me out how can I fix this at free of cost coz I heard Heroku is a free platform where u can deploy your Nodejs app.

Any answer is appreciated =)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly add a screesnhot of the issue you are facing or in case of Heroku, you can paste the log as well which you can find under ACTIVITY tab of your Heroku applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku free apps do not use SSL. You will need to change to a paid plan to get it.

However, as a workaround, if you want to see "secure" in the browser, you can use free cloudflare account, using cloudflare as a dns proxy. Cloudflare will use HTTPS (secure) when your site is proxied through them, and can use HTTP when it retrieves your site.

It is not secure at all between cloudflare and heroku, but is an easy workaround for demo apps etc.

Here is what the SSL setting should look like:

[image]

and the DNS record:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer and also i am really sorry to respond after a long time. Just wanted to ask, can i get a  free domain like how would we get in heroku(like myappsucks.herokuapp.com)?

Comment: on cloudflare? I don't think so... there are lots of places to get cheap domains.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the help btw =D